# Get the X,Y coordinate on a square, based on the square center + angle

Tags: .net, math, graph, geometry, trigonometry

In a winform application, I've to draw some graphic according to a configuration.

I'm looking the cleanest way to get the X;Y coordinates located ON a square, based on an angle. This angle(in degree) is given in the mathematical convention(0° on the right, 90° on the top, ...)and represent the direction in which we search those coordinates.

I know this is not very clear, so I created  some schematic, it will be much cleaner:
[image]

What I know: The side of the square is : `2*R`, R represent then the radius of the inner circle.

I'm looking to find the X;Y coordinate in the red circle.

For now I've an algorithm that resolve the issue depending of the angle:

**A)**
if we have an angle between 305° and 45°, we knows the X value( =R), and compute the Y:

```
Y = R / cos(α) * sin(α)
```

**B)**
if we have an angle between 45° and 135°, we knows the Y value( =R), and compute the X:

```
...
```

First I'm not sure it will works in all case, and it makes 4 times almost the same code.

Do you have an idea on how to make this cleaner?

(I developp in c# .net, so if you know something that helps me in the libs, can be nice)

**EDIT**
Maybe I found a clean way, do you think it will works or there is simplier?
The idea is to convert a polar value in a cartesian. In order to do this, we have to compute the amplitude.

```
αTemp = α % Math.PI /2; //We put it in the first quarter, it will not change the amplitude.
amplitude = R /cos(αTemp);
```

The we only have to convert [polar into cartesian](http://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html):

```
X = cos(α) * amplitude;
Y = sin(α) * amplitude;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the simplest case of an angle less than 45 degrees in the first quadrant, you can see that the triangle formed with the point on the circle is a similar triangle to the one formed with point on the square.

[image]

So the y value is r times the tangent of the angle.  This is not a continuous function, so you can break it into 8 separate pieces - one for each half quadrant.  In c#:

```
    public struct Point
    {
        public double X;
        public double Y;
    }


    public static Point calculatePointOnSquare(double r, double angleInDegrees)
    {
        Point p;
        p.X = 0.0;
        p.Y = 0.0;

        double angle = (angleInDegrees % 360) * Math.PI /180;

        double angleModPiOverTwo = angle % (Math.PI/4);

        if (angle >= 0 && angle < Math.PI / 4)
        {
            p.X = r;
            p.Y = r * Math.Tan(angle);
        }
        else if (angle >= Math.PI / 4 && angle < Math.PI / 2)
        {
            p.X = r * Math.Tan(Math.PI/2 - angle);
            p.Y = r;
        }
        else if (angle >= Math.PI / 2 && angle < 3*Math.PI/4)
        {
            p.X = -1 * r * Math.Tan(angle % (Math.PI/4));
            p.Y = r;
        }
        else if (angle >= 3*Math.PI/4 && angle < Math.PI)
        {
            p.X = -1 * r;
            p.Y = r * Math.Tan(Math.PI - angle);
        }
        else if (angle >= Math.PI && angle < 5*Math.PI/4)
        {
            p.X = -1 * r;
            p.Y = -1 * r * Math.Tan(angle % (Math.PI/4));
        }
        else if (angle >= 5*Math.PI/4 && angle < 3*Math.PI/2)
        {
            p.X = -1 * r * Math.Tan(3*Math.PI/2 - angle);
            p.Y = -1 * r;
        }
        else if (angle >= 3*Math.PI/2 && angle < 7*Math.PI/4)
        {
            p.X = r * Math.Tan(angle % (Math.PI/4));
            p.Y = -1 * r;
        }
        else
        {
            p.X = r;
            p.Y = -1 * r * Math.Tan(2 * Math.PI - angle);
        }

        return p;
    }
```

Comment: Too dirty, sorry :/, my working code with 4 lines is currently much easier/cleaner

Comment: Why are you using mod of 360 over here? `double angle = (angleInDegrees % 360) * Math.PI /180;`. I think it should be `double angle = angleInDegrees * Math.PI /180;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
if (Cos(Alpha) <>  0) and (Abs(Tg(Alpha)) <= 1)  then 
                                             //on vertical edge
    Y = R * Tg(Alpha) * Sign(Sin(Alpha))    //see picture below
    X = R * Sign(Cos(Alpha))               //left or right  edge
else              
                                           //on horizontal edge
    X = R * Cot(Alpha) * Sign(Cos(Alpha))
    Y = R * Sign(Sin(Alpha))                //top or bottom
```

wiki picture about tangent:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a solution that distinguishes between four cases, namely the quadrant the angle is in (0-90 degrees, 90-180 degrees, 180-270 degrees and 270-360 degrees). For each case, only two sides of the rectangle are interesting. For these, calculate the intersection points and take the one that is closer to the center.

To formulate it differently, if you have some code for ray-line-intersection at hand, consider the ray defined by the center and the angle and the four lines defined by the rectangle's sides. Calculate intersection parameters for the ray and the four lines and take the minimum coefficient of all non-negative coefficients; this will be the coefficient defining the desired intersection point.

Comment: Yeah, but this would bring 4 time the same kind of code. I've already a working example with this and it's not very nice